# Exprort to Excel not working in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using laravel 8 and livewire datatables . Not working pagination buttons and export to excel button.

Comment: Exporting to excel isn't really related with Livewire. We need to see some code to make further assumptions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have not already done so, you can take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).